# How to change the height responsively for an icon from FontAwesomeIcons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, icons, font-awesome

I have an Icon from `FontAwesomeIcons` and need to change its height responsively, but I cannot use `MediaQuery` because it doesn't have a height attribute, it just has a size attribute which is not responsive like using `MediaQuery` with height.

This is my code:

```
Icon(
  FontAwesomeIcons.solidFlag,
  color: Colors.grey,
  size: 20,
),
```

And in the same screen I have this code which works responsively:

```
Image.asset(
  'assets/icons/handphone.png',
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .04,
),
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MediaQuery it is responsive with device height and width.
Please see below code :

```
SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3),
```

You can set size of icon by calculating either width or height of screen as per requirement.

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

Will give you height of whole device you can calculate aspect ratio accordingly.

thanks.